# CURL not showing output for multiple requests and progress meter

Tags: macos, curl, https, terminal

Previous versions of cURl would show range and progress of a multiple requests in Mac Terminal i.e `curl "site.com/[a-z].html"`

the output would be something to the effect of

```
[1/26] site.com/a.html
content response
[2/26] site.com/a.html
etc..etc
```

My updated version has the output but doesn't show the request progress and url which was better for formatting and tracking. If I can enable that in the latest curl please let me know how to enable it.

Here's an example, it used to do this by default  in the terminal i.imgur.com/zERO28n.png

Comment: The `curl` command doesn't display the progress bar by default -- it displays a progress meter. You probably had a shell alias that enabled the progress bar and changed your shell configuration so that the alias is no longer being used. Beyond that guess I'll point out you didn't provide enough useful information. What version of macOS and curl? What was the exact curl command?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know curl has no built in support for showing which request of a batch is currently processing. What you can enable is verbose mode and a progress bar using this command:

```
curl -v -# "https://example.com/[a-z].html"
```

You can use -# or --progress-bar

Comment: Here's an example, it used to do this by default <stdout> in the terminal 

https://i.imgur.com/zERO28n.png